# Jaxb marshalling to wrong character

Tags: java, utf-8, jaxb

I used to marshall my models by calling there toXml():

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MyModel {

    private String body;

    public String getBody() {
        return this.body;
    }

    public void setBody(final String _body) {
        this.body = _body;
    }

    public String toXML() throws JAXBException {
        final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyModel.class);
        final Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        final StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(this, writer);
        return writer.toString();
    }
}
```

If I write this to a file or via a stream to a webdav-target, it leads to an invalid xml when using i.e. `ä` as a textvalue.

```
final MyModel m = new MyModel();
m.setBody("\u00E4");

final FileWriter w = new FileWriter("D:\\outtest.xml");
w.write(m.toXML());
w.close();
```

The XMl is something like this (looks other in npp and is correct there, when switching to ansi):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><myModel><body>伯</body></myModel>
```

I need a hint to solve this!

---

OK, this works as it should (Thx!):

```
final MyModel m = new MyModel();
m.setBody("\u00E4");
final FileOutputStream s = new FileOutputStream("D:\\outtest.xml");
final OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(s, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
osw.write(m.toXML());
osw.close();
```

My problem now is, that this file-testing was the simplified version ;-)
I call toXml() and write this string an JPA-moodel. Later this should be written to webdav using a framework-class whichs takes an ByteArrayInputStream as input. So I use this code:

```
final ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(jpaModel.getXmlString().getBytes());
```

...and writing this I finally got it. Using the 'more detailed' `getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))` helps me out! Thanks

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean as "an invalid XML"? What is the result, and in what way is it invalid? Are you perhaps encoding the result using something other than UTF-8 later? (That would certainly be a problem.)

Comment: The xml is written to a file and when I open it in a browser or in notepad++, it is shown as 'invalid'. There is an `xE4` where `ä` should be.

Comment: Well you haven't shown how you're writing the XML to a file, and it's not clear what you mean by "xE4". What *bytes* are in the file? (And please show the code you're using to write it - I strongly suspect you're using the wrong encoding.)

Comment: I need a bit longer to update the sources, sry!

Comment: That's okay, I've seen everything I need now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, now we know how you're writing the file, this is the problem:

```
FileWriter w = new FileWriter("D:\\outtest.xml");
```

That will *always* use the platform-default encoding - even though you've told JAXB that you're going to be using UTF-8. It's a bit like creating the data for a JPEG, but then saving it as a `.png` file. Use a `FileOutputStream` wrapped in an `OutputStreamWriter` using UTF-8, and all should be well.

If you're using Java 7, you can simplify this:

```
try (Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    writer.write(m.toXML());
}
```

Alternatively, you might want to change your `toXML` method to accept an `OutputStream` to write the data to, instead of returning a string.

Comment: I added my 2nd problem but solved it. The platform-defaulthint helped me out.